# No module named pip in Windows7, Python32

Tags: python

I am using Windows7, Python 3.2.3. Command:

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

> Error: No module named pip

Answer (score 1):

You need to have [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py). You can save by `CTRL + S` or `CMD + S` and locate get-pip.py with your terminal. Then run `python get-pip.py`. This will install `pip` into your local computer. After that you can use `pip install pandas` or `pip3 install pandas`

Answer (score 0):

It's just `pip install` no python

And if you still can't find it, You have to check your environment variables include the path to pip

Answer (score 0):

you don't have pip. open cmd, and type

```
Python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably dont have pip installed yet, im pretty sure you can do that when installing the python idle, otherwise you can change it in the "system control" -> programs and features -> "python" and then click change and set the cross where you need it
Pip install and python -m pip install do the exact same btw.